# How to find count of files in a zip through adm-zip(node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to get the number of files in my zip file. I used adm-zip.So i tried using following:-

```
 var unzip=require('adm-zip');

 var zip=new unzip("hello.zip");
 console.log(zip.getEntries().length);
```

Now in my `hello.zip` file I have 5 files, but the count of `zip.getEntries().length` is **6**.

`zip.getEntries()` returns array of objects from what I read. Can someone please help me on this? How I get the correct count of number of files?

Comment: Are you sure it's not 5 files _in a directory_? A directory takes a separate entry in the ZIP file. Try this: `console.log( zip.getEntries().map((e) => e.entryName) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why its giving 1 more than what's expected. I have 2 suggestions for you. Have a check at both.

1. Change the path of the file that you are planning to unzip to-

   `var zip=new unzip("./hello.zip");`
2. Check if there are any hidden files or links(like the `.git`)

Also, to answer your question on how to find the length, just validate the above points and also try this-

```
var zipEntries = zip.getEntries()
zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
    count++;
}
```

Hope it helps! :) Happy coding!